# jQuery Replace Breaking Links in Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I'm experiencing an issue when using jQuery to replace phone numbers and certain texts in paragraphs. What's happening is when I use the bit of jQuery below, it either hides or diables links in in my pages. In most of the sites we build, all we want is to replace phone numbers sitewide and not regular text. In the code below, I'm only trying to exclude the site-title because it get wrapped automatically in a `<p>` tag and if I don't exclude it, it kills the website's main logo.

Help!

```
jQuery(function($) {

// NUM SWAP
  $('p').not('.site-title').each(function() {
    var num1 = $(this).text().replace(/800-218-4243/g, "844-853-7373");
    $(this).text(num1);
  });

  $('p').not('.site-title').each(function() {
    var num2 = $(this).text().replace(/330-836-0210/g, "844-853-7373");
    $(this).text(num2);
  });

});
```

EDIT/UPDATE WITH SOME MORE INFO:

Replacing of the number in the browser is for call tracking for our clients and to preserve the SEO strength of the original phone number. Below is a page link to look at. I'd like you to check the page with javascript enabled and then disabled. For example, have a look at the author name link and comment link just below the title of the blog post and you'll see that with javascript enabled, the links disappear Then, when you disable javascript, the links return as well as a couple of blue buttons 'See Tetimonials' & 'See Case Results' in the sidebar return too.

http://1ohio.us/worst-vehicle-models-for-personal-injury-insurance-claims

Comment: make a working fiddle. and tell what is error

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why don't you replace the numbers at the server side ? By this, each visitor doesn't have to run a script to replace these numbers.

Comment: So what is your exact string and by which string you want to replace ?

Comment: Please have another look at my original post. I've edited it and added a link to a page for you guys to have a look at. Additionally, i've added some more info in my edit as well.

Comment: So you basically are fooling search engines by replacing the phone numbers? You do know that if for example Google checks this your website might get thrown out of their search index right?

Comment: Actually, no, the intention isn't to fool anything or anyone. The intention is to preserve their traditional number while displaying an updated phone number to site visitors for call tracking and lead generation.